# How to add android to cordova platform? Getting a PATH error?

Tags: android, eclipse, bash, cordova

I am trying to add android as a cordova platform so that I can build apps with phonegap. When I tried to add android thus:

cordova platform add android

I received this error message:

Error: The command "android" failed. Make sure you have the latest Android SDK installed, and the "android" command (inside the tools/ folder) is added to your path.

I do have the latest Android SDK installed and just modified the bash profile by adding this:

export PATH=${PATH}:/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools:/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/tools

For some reason when I run "cordova platform add android" I am still getting this error?

Comment: As your error indicates i think you must update your sdk using sdk manager

Answer (score 0):

Your SDK is not being detected or you have an outdated version.

1. Ensure you have updated your SDK.
2. Open another Terminal.

Comment: Everything was just downloaded today.